# Ramifications of public next pointer in Node class

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

basic Linked List Data Structure.

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(int num);

private:
    int data_;
    Node * next_;
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList();

    void insertAtFront(int toAdd);
    void insertAtEnd(int num);

private:
    Node * head_;
};


....


void LinkedList::insertAtFront(int toAdd) {
    if (head_ == NULL) {
        head_ = new Node(toAdd);
    }
    else {
        Node * current = head_;
        while (current->next_ != NULL) { //problem in question

        }
    }
}
```

This is a rough, far from finished implementation, obviously, so don't judge me on the syntax yet. But I had a question about the obvious warning that my IDE threw at me. Mainly that next_ is private so while loop doesn't work. current->next is inaccessible.

Early in my programming class I had it beaten into me that all class variables should be private/protected always under pretty much all circumstances. Now I can go the obvious route, add a recursive function within the Node class itself that handles the insertion and call it from head_, etc. etc.

OR, and stay with me here, I could just set next_ to public? I really don't see why not. Since main() would only have access to the nodes indirectly through the private head_ pointer, and the actual "data" of the node is private, is there a reason to also keep next_ private?

Comment: I have two suggestions: First move the `Node` class to be inside the `LinkedList` class, as it should be private to the list class anyway. And to fix your problem you make the `LinkedList` class a `friend` of the `Node` class.

Answer (score 0):

This advice is still good. You should not expose these fields. Instead, you should either:

1. Declare "LinkedList" as a friend of "Node"
2. Move "Node" into "LinkedList"

(Personally I recommend putting "Node" in a "details" or "internal" namespace, adding "LinkedList" as a friend of Node, and creating a "typedef details::Node Node" in the private section of LinkedList unless you intend for other code to use Node, in which case you might also want to consider making public accessor functions that give read only access to the fields -- in that particular case, I would still have a typedef to "Node" within LinkedList though, in that case, I would make the typedef public).

Either of these approaches will grant LinkedList, but just LinkedList, access.

To answer your question regarding the dangers of making it public, some dangers include:

1. If you change the name or structure of the internal implementation and it is public, you risk breaking external users that have come to rely on these internal implementation details.
2. You remove the ability to enforce reasonable constraints or be assured of certain assumptions regarding the structure of your data. For example, exposing "next_" would allow a malicious (or incompetent) user of the code to unlink nodes without deleting them or to link nodes circularly in a linked list that was assumed to not be circular. Once you expose internal data members, all bets are off regarding any assumptions that can be made about their structure and values.

Comment: I was also taught, about the same time when I was taught to always keep things private, that 'friend' should be avoided whenever possible. That it was only to be used when you had coded yourself into a corner and had no other choice.

Comment: Friendship is very similar to package level access in Java. Friendship should indeed be generally avoided and it certainly should be avoided in cases where the components are unrelated or where the components belong to separate projects or teams. In this case, a LinkedList Node is a part of the internal implementation details of a LinkedList. The two are tightly interrelated and are a part of a single logical unit. Thus this is a reasonable application of friendship.